# "Failed to unmount partitions" during installation Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: partitioning, installation, unmount

I have multi-boot with Windows 7, Linux Mint, Kubuntu and then I was installing Ubuntu 11.10 too but during the installation it appears this message:

> failed to unmount partitions. migration-assistant needs to mount a partition but cannot do so because the following mount point could not be unmounted: /dev/sda6. Please close any applications using these mount points...

What can I do?

Comment: What is partition /dev/sda6 ? swap ?

Comment: fdisk -l [provide the output]

Answer (score 1):

The obvious question is whether you closed any applications using these mount point; the usual suspects are a file manager or even the terminal, but anything can be using it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found [this advice](https://superuser.com/questions/383667/how-to-multiboot-ubuntu-11-10-with-another-linux).

> You can install Ubuntu on your system by following steps:
>
> 1. Boot your system with Ubuntu Live CD
> 2. Select 'try Ubuntu'
> 3. Open terminal and type `sudo ubiquity --no-migration-assistant`
> 4. Follow with the installation window as usual.
>
> This means you need to disable migration assistant, so you cannot import informations from user and Firefox in CentOS. That's all.